# Static methods with HttpContext and database connections

Tags: c#, static-methods

I just got a project that have some core classes that uses static methods.

It is a C# project, with an interface that reflects some methods to javascript.
In this interface, there are a lot of calls to static methods that uses HttpContext and get data from database (actually just one access database), such as this (some methods have some logic inside):

```
public static string UsrId {
    get{
        try {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["usrid"].ToString();
        } catch(NullReferenceException) {
            return ServiceVars.GuestId;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is:

Is this a bad pratice? What are the cons (and pros?) of doing this?

I read somewhere that static methods that uses database connections are bad for high traffic sites, because it would queue up the requests. Is this true? Or should I not worry about database connection in static methods?

And what about the HttpContext inside static methods, is it bad and why?

Comment: What's bad here is the catch of `NullReferenceException`. Don't ever do that.

Comment: One con of using a lot of static methods is that they can become an obstacle if you later decide that you want to use "[dependency injection](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html)", such as if you are trying to build a set of unit tests for your code.  Regarding your comment about database connections...there's nothing inherent to the nature of static methods that would cause such a problem. It would depend on how someone has implemented their particular database connection code, regardless of whether static methods were used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's bad here is the catch of `NullReferenceException`. Don't ever do that.

Instead, check for null first:

```
public static string UsrId {
    get{
        var userId = HttpContext.Current.Session["usrid"];
        if (userId == null) { return ServiceVars.GuestId;}
        return userId .ToString();
    }
}
```

Also, the problem you may be referring to isn't a problem with static methods, or with `HttpContext`. It's a problem with using `Session` state.

Comment: +1 avoid all exceptions if you can.  If there is some way of getting out without throwing an exception take that route.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that :) It is fixed now. But about the static methods, no cons on using it with database calls or HttpContext?

Comment: Again, the cons you were referring to had to do with using `Session` state. They have nothing to do with using static methods.